# Using Xpath and reading values from same attribute name

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I am parsing a XML document using Xpath. The steps node have Attributes in the form of step. I am trying to get the value of each step.  For example 0.03, 0.025,0.05....  But with my Code I only get the 1st value i.e 0.03 in the list of strings. Here is the  Code that I tried:

[XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOYiJ.png)

```
private void btn_steps_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> step = new List<string>();

    XmlDocument doctst = new XmlDocument();

    doctst.Load(@"C:\ehData\workData\mywork.xml");

    XmlNodeList nodelistst = doctst.Selectnodes("//steps");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodelistst)
    {
        step.Add(node["step"].InnerText);
    }

    listBox2.DataSource = step;
}
```

Moreover, I am attaching the XML file image that I am trying to parse. What I am doing wrong in this Code?

Here are the few lines of the XML file

```
<devices orderNo="67354698">
    <device serno="P1002001190">
      <steps>
        <step descriptor="160000556" element="1" usage="B">0.03</step>
        <step descriptor="160000556" element="2" usage="B">0.025</step>
        <step descriptor="160000556" element="3" usage="B">0.05</step>
```

Comment: Please post the Xml data as text here - don't expect people here to re-type your data just to reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: Much easier to do use Xml Linq which is a new Net a Library method than standard xml library.

Comment: I have added the XML file as an Image. Please look at it.  I cannot post the text bcauseit is very Long.

Comment: @Sohaib, I added my answer with output below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** By using **`XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName()`** with xml tag name

```
...

XmlNodeList nodelistst1 = doctst.GetElementsByTagName("step");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelistst1)
{
    step.Add(node.InnerText);
}
```

**2)** By using **`XmlDocument.SelectNodes()`** with XPath

```
...

XmlNodeList nodelistst = doctst.SelectNodes(".//devices/device/steps/step/text()");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelistst)
{
    step.Add(node.Value);
}
```

So finally your result from both of the above option would be

```
foreach (var item in step)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**Output:** (For provided text XML from OP)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you want attribute value or you want inner text.
Hence I am putting everything here.

**Retrieving attributes:**

For getting `descriptor` attribute from first `step` element - you can use below XPath:

```
/devices/device/steps/step[1]/@descriptor
```

This XPath will return - `descriptor="160000556"`

If you want only value then you can use:

```
string(/devices/device/steps/step[1]/@descriptor)
```

This would return only value i.e. `160000556`

Same strategy you can apply for element or usage attributes.

**Retrieving Inner Text:**

And for getting inner text of second `step` element, you can use below XPath:

```
/devices/device/steps/step[2]/text()
```

Now these XPaths you can run through loop and change index inside square brackets to get all attributes and elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: HI. Thanks for Posting the Code. Actually I want the inner-text i.e 0.03,0.025,0.5 in a list of string.